# Firebase cloud function server architecture

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Before getting into the main question, I will explain my predicament:

We need to search our records using criteria that Firebase currently does not support (e.g., querying the data using multiple conditionals, though it does look like firestore might have that feature). The options seem to be that we could either 1) asynchronously do multiple calls to the firebase database, using filters for each call and then compare the results from the cloud function and send the results to the browser, or 2) do one call to the firebase database, potentially retrieving thousands of records, and then just manually filter through the results within the cloud function, before returning the results to the browser.

Of course, we will probably have to make a case-by-case decision, depending on the nature of the query. But what would be helpful to know is: how much latency is there between the server that runs the cloud functions and the firebase database? Or are they on the same server? Also, are there any potential concerns for processing thousands of records in the cloud function?

Comment: If you want add a search feature, you can do this with firestore:

Example you want search a record name "Post Title"
In firestore you should define data as below:

"Post": true
"Title": true

And used query whereField("Post", equal: true) to matched record.

Comment: Yeah, trying to stay off firestore until it gets out of beta though :/